# How to call a model when element on select tag changed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a select that show the options of product. When I change the product within the select tag, i want to call a model to retrieve a material related to selected product and show the retreived data from mySQL on element.

The select tag is giving the code (primary key) of the product. How can i do to reach my purpose?

What i know so far is to bind the select tag and listen to change event, and then i don't know what to do. Is it possible to call php function inside script tag? and if so, how can i put the retrieved data to the view?

Comment: on `change` of dropdown, call ajax and get data as per selected item, and display where you want.

Comment: what did you try so far from tutorials point or w3school?

Comment: please drop some your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
 url: 'your url /test', //Set url to your controller 
    data: {
      productId: x,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function success(data) {
          //Display data
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
    }
  });
} // Now go make something amazing!
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>


create a new view 

json/json_view.php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($my_data); ?>


in your controller 

public function test(){

           $this-> MODEL -> FUNCTION ($this->input->post('productId'));
   $data["my_data"]  = $data['1'];
            $this->load->view('json/json_example_view', $data);
 }
```